# variable is undeclared (first use in this function) error in C

Tags: c

I implemented the function *free_list* that called in the end of the program to free the list I created.

```
void free_list(node* node)
{
   node* temp = NULL;

   while(node != NULL) {
      temp = node;
      node = node->next;
      free(temp);
    }
}
```

but the **GCC** tell me that - "temp" undeclared (first use in this function).
What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Name of the parameter `node` hides the name of the struct/class `node`.

Rename the parameter:

```
void free_list(node* node_ptr)
{
   node* temp = NULL;

   while(node_ptr != NULL) {
      temp = node_ptr;
      node_ptr = node_ptr->next;
      free(temp);
    }
}
```